# How to request permission upon FB login

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I try to follow a tutor that shows how to have a LogIn button and how to log in to FB.

The code follows -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '521597764587246', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                // TODO: Handle the access token

                // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                form.setAttribute("action", '/FacebookLogin.ashx');

                var field = document.createElement("input");
                field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                form.appendChild(field);

                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            }
        });

    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
</script>
```

What I am trying to achieve is a permmision to write on user wall.

**How can I get other permissions upon login?**

Comment: You are not doing Facebook login in that code at all. If you don't know the very basics of how Facebook login for apps works, please start by reading the official documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a facebook auth that requests the 'publishstream' permissions which is what you need to publish a status update on behalf of a facebook user.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status == "connected") {
            //User is logged into facebook and has authorized your app proceed with wall post
        });
} else if (response.status == "not_authorized") {
    //User is logged in to facebook but has not authorized your app
} else if (response.status == "unknown") {
    //User is not logged in to facebook
}
});

//This example uses jQuery and a button with id="#fb-login-button", just put the contained code below in whatever click handler your using for your facebook login button
$("#fb-login-button").click(function () {
    FB.login($.proxy(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //User has autorized proceed with wall post
        } else {
            //User did not autorize
        }
    }, this), {
        //Scope is where you specify permissions
        scope: 'publish_stream'
    });
});
```